# Уникальная идентификация пользователя

Tags: windows, winapi

Десктопному приложению нужно уникально идентифицировать *пользователя или компьютер*. Например, уникальный `ID` присваиваемый `TeamViewer`'ом компьютеру, не меняется даже после переустановки `ОС`.
Какие есть способы уникальной идентификации?
**UPD**
Просьба отдельно указывать на способы, где нет необходимости ассемблерного кода, только `WinAPI`, применимые для пользователей с ограниченными правами

Comment: windows в любом случае для каждого пользователя и компьютера генерирует уникальные идентификаторы. где искать:  
юзер - откройте ветку реестра HKEY_USERS  
комп - хз

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В таких случаях, обычно, цепляются к железу. Например, можно получить CPUID и выдернуть из него серийный номер процессора. Серийник материнки тоже сойдет.

Главное, чтобы язык/платформа программирования позволяли до железа добраться так или иначе.

**UPD.** Кстати, никакого ассемблерного кода тут не нужно ) Все через винапи.

Answer (score 1):

Индификатор проца
Серийник материнки
Серийник винчестера
На практике используется комбинация нескольких параметров.

Как точка отправления [WMI](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WMI)